# Discord.py "TypeError: Object of type View is not JSON serializable"

Tags: button, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a Discord bot and I've encountered this error when trying to use a slash command to send a button:

```
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type View is not JSON serializable
```

How could I fix this code so that it runs properly?

```
from interactions import Client, slash_command, SlashContext
import discord

bot = Client(token="(hidden for privacy reasons)")

class View(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Button", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You pressed the button.")

@slash_command(
    name="button",
    description="Send a button."
)
async def button(ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.send(
        view=View()
    )
    
bot.start()
```

I've removed everything else that the slash command should have returned (images, text, answer prompt), used various templates and even reinstalled discord.py, but the error remains the same.

Comment: You are not using [`discord.py`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py).